# Rewriting nginx URL's

Tags: nginx

I need to setup nginx to rewrite URL's from `example.com/page1/page2` to `example.com/#page1/page2`, in order to make backbone.js´s Routing work.

Basically it's all about the `#` that needs to be appended after the first slash in the URL to make it work.

But how do I do that? I can't really find any good example online.

The current nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/frontend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /index.html#$1/$2 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since fragment URLs are processed client side, you need to redirect the user with a 301/302. Try the 'permanent' flag

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/frontend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrites;
}

location @rewrites {
    rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /#$1/$2 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that unfortunately leads to 404's all over the place

Comment: @Industrial Does the URL show in the browser correctly? The URL shown should be /index.html#some/path

Comment: Yep. `example.com/index.html#page/query` leads to 404 as it is

Comment: @Industrial Then it's a problem with your frontend code, the rewrite is doing what you're asking it do do. If you take off the `index.html` bit and make the rewrite `rewrite ^/~(.*)/(.*)/? /#$1/$2 permanent;` the result will be exactly as you specified in your question

Comment: Oh. I tried that as well and same result. However using `rewrite ^ /#$uri redirect;` makes it work, but it appends double slashes to the final url. Any ideas?